# Symfony CollectionType and Doctrine : Remove null items

Tags: json, forms, symfony, graphql

I'm having an issue with Symfony's CollectionType.
My project is an API, receiving form values as JSON input.

I want to be able to update an entity named "Reservation", which has a collection of items (called "ReservationItems", each item is an embedded form of type "ReservationItemType" :

```
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add(
                'reservationItems',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => ReservationItemType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'delete_empty' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Reservation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of `ReservationItemType` :

```
class ReservationItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'name',
                TextType::class,
                [
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'status',
                TextType::class,
                [
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ReservationItem::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the Reservation entity definition :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReservationRepository::class)]
class Reservation
{
    // ...

    /** @var ReservationItem[]|ArrayCollection */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'reservation', targetEntity: ReservationItem::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $reservationItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reservationItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ReservationItem>
     */
    public function getReservationItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->reservationItems;
    }

    public function addReservationItem(ReservationItem $reservationItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->reservationItems->contains($reservationItem)) {
            $this->reservationItems->add($reservationItem);
            $reservationItem->setReservation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeReservationItem(ReservationItem $reservationItem): self
    {
        if ($this->reservationItems->removeElement($reservationItem)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($reservationItem->getReservation() === $this) {
                $reservationItem->setReservation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And here is the ReservationItem entity definition :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReservationItemRepository::class)]
class ReservationItem
{
    // ...

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Reservation::class, inversedBy: 'reservationItems')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Reservation $reservation = null;

    public function getReservation(): ?Reservation
    {
        return $this->reservation;
    }

    public function setReservation(?Reservation $reservation): self
    {
        $this->reservation = $reservation;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

From my client app, here is what I am sending :

```
{
  "reservation": {
    "reservationItems": [
      { "name": "Foo", "status": "PENDING"},
      null,
      { "name": "Bar", "status": "PENDING"}
    ]
  }
]
```

In Symfony's doc, each example is based on `form-data`, which can be represented by :

```
reservation[reservationItems][0][name]: Foo
reservation[reservationItems][0][status]: PENDING
reservation[reservationItems][2][name]: Bar
reservation[reservationItems][2][status]: PENDING
```

This results in an indexed PHP array, with missing index "1".
Symfony considers former item which was indexed as 1 is missing, and delete this item.

But in JSON, it is not possible to manually index an array, with missing values.
My solution is to send `null` on indexes which must be deleted.
But Symfony is ignoring null values, and doesn't call `Reservation::removeReservationItem` method, even with `by_reference` set to false.

I'm using GraphQL, with [webonyx/graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php). I tried another solution by sending an object instead of an array, but the library ignores "indexes"...

Did someone has met this issue (with GraphQL or REST or other JSON based protocol) ?
Do you have any advice ?

I have followed Symfony's recommandations by setting delete_empty to true, and even with required set to false or empty_data set to null, nothing works as expected.

Comment: Can you show the entity class with the relation mapping?

Comment: I've just added my entities' definition in the original post